Spatie Browsershot Image Watermark - position and general issues with docs
I'm trying to add a watermark to an image that has been captured by the Spatie Browsershot package. The image is working great, even the watermark is, but I can't make any modifications to it.
I'm using Laravel 11 on Valet, PHP 8.2, and Imagick is installed and appears to be working.
The documents make it sound like you just add a position like this $image->watermark('watermark.png', AlignPosition::center); but I get an error saying "Undefined constant Spatie\Image\Enums\AlignPosition::center" I've added "use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot" and "use Spatie\Image\Image", and I even tried adding "use Spatie\Image\Enums\AlignPosition", but it's not working. I've even tried loading the image again after it's saved in case it depended on the Image class.
Here is my code:
use Spatie\Image\Image;
use Spatie\Image\Enums\AlignPosition;

Route::get('/test/{id}', function($id) {

    Browsershot::url('http://msa.test/maintenance-schedules/1/print')
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg', 100)
    ->fullPage()
    ->windowSize(1024, 768)
    ->save('temp/msa_test'.$id.'.jpeg');

    $image = Image::load('temp/msa_test'.$id.'.jpeg');

    $image->watermark('images/pams_network_watermark.png', AlignPosition::center);

    return 'Done!';
});

I'm obviously missing something here, and I'd like to learn how to use it so I can contribute to the docs for when other newbies like me come along, because this is way harder than it should be.
